# i have 100*100 matrix, how can i make plot3 graph?

Tags: matlab, graph

I have a `100 x 100` matrix and i have to use `plot3` in MATLAB environment to graph this data. I tried `plot3(matrix name)` but I faced this error "not enough input arguments". I think `plot3` needs 3 input arguments, but I only have this matrix of data. could anyone help me to solve this problem? Is there any alternative for `plot3` when we don't have enough arguments?
I need a graph like this:

[image]

Comment: OK so you have a 2D, 100x100 matrix, how are you suppose to transform it into a 3D plot? Can you provide more details? Some code examples? What have you tried?

Comment: i have added a graph to my question could you please check it? that graph only shows 5 rows of data but i need 100. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to plot the values in a figure as a sort of surface element. What you can do then is:

```
[X,Y] = size(matrix);
figure;
surface(1:X,1:Y,matrix);
```

What this does is that it creates a vector for both `X` and `Y` indices, as possible in `surface`. The `X` and `Y` indices are obtained by setting them as integers from `1:size`, so basically you assign the location of each matrix element to an index.

Note that you can strictly speaking use `surface(matrix)` as well, but the former approach allows you to use custom indexing, as long as the lengths of the vectors `X` and `Y` are the same as the size of your matrix.

For the `waterfall` use:

```
figure;
waterfall(matrix);
```

Sample code:

```
A=rand(100);
figure;
waterfall(1:100,1:100,A);
```

Gives:

[image: waterfallplot]

where you can play around with the `name-value` pairs, see the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waterfall.html) on that.

Comment: thank you very much. i have added a graph to my question could you please check it? i need something like that , but that graph only shows 5 rows of data but i need 100. thanks

Comment: I have tried waterfall( ), but it doesnt give what i need :(

Comment: Why not? It plots lines the same way as `plot3`, only that it uses a continuous colour scale.

Comment: Thank you so much Adriaan! you are very nice person. i have been tried waterfall( ), and tried again, but i am not sure about this function! because by this graph i can not understand the data clearly.

Comment: Well, plotting a hundred lines in one graph is bound to be messy and vague. I still think it's better to just use a `surface` graph and look at the colour changes.

Comment: `waterfall` is what I would have used. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `mesh` or `surf` instead of `plot3`.

`plot3` draws a line in 3d-space, so it will need three vectors of the same length (one for each dimension).

When you have a matrix, one reasonable way of displaying it is as a surface in 3d space, which is done by the functions `mesh` and `surf`.
Try it out! I hope i helps!

Comment: thank you very much. i have added a graph to my question could you please check it? i need something like that , but that graph only shows 5 rows of data but i need 100. thanks

Comment: So you want all 100 lines and not a surface?

Comment: yeah exactly same as picture.

Comment: Check the `waterfall` as presented in my answer. That should do the trick for you.